# What is the difference between the KDEMO and DEMO projects?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

I'm writing a paper on the future of fusion technology and I can't seem to find the difference between Europe's [DEMO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEMO) experiment and Korea's [KDEMO](http://www.nature.com/news/south-korea-makes-billion-dollar-bet-on-fusion-power-1.12251) except for the fact that they are both planned to follow [ITER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITER) which involves Korea and many European states and that they of course will be in different locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this talk by Neil Mitchell (slide 4)](https://indico.cern.ch/conferenceDisplay.py?confId=288051) there are two different strategies.

EU, US, and Japan are planning a "pure fusion" reactor in which the $14~MeV$ neutrons resulting from the fusion reaction are directly converted to heat.

China and Korea are studying for a hybrid reactor in which those neutrons will be used to catalyse a fission reaction in spent fuel from existing Pressurised Water Reactors.

Answer (score 1):

According to [ITER newsline](http://www.iter.org/newsline/255/1481), DEMO is a generic name for the successor of ITER. K-DEMO is the Korean concept for DEMO.